# How to enable routing in OS X El Capitan

Tags: macos, routes, osx-elcapitan

I've got a Linux VMware virtual machine (guest) configured with a NAT adapter on a 192.168.56.0 subnet. Its IP address is 192.168.56.128 and my Mac (host) got 192.168.56.1. Guest's default gateway is automatically set to 192.168.56.2 and is able to ping google. Host's Wi-Fi IP is 192.168.0.2,

I've configured my Wi-Fi router with following routing table to forward packets of 192.168.56.0 to 192.168.0.2 (my Mac)

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ route

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         172.16.4.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
172.16.4.0      *               255.255.252.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.56.0    192.168.0.2     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.57.0    192.168.0.2     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 wlan0
```

But I'm unable to ping guest from any other device on the Wi-Fi network (192.168.0.0). So it's obvious that my Mac running OS X El Capitan is not forwarding the packets from 192.168.0.0 to 192.168.56.0

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about your specific case.  In my case I just had two ethernets on the same MacMini and one host being one of these ethernets.  The only thing I had to do is `sudo sysctl -w net.inet.ip.forwarding=1`

https://roelant.net/2015/share-your-vpn-mac-el-capitan.html however noted another variable as well (`sudo sysctl -w net.inet.ip.fw.enable=1`) and went into a NAT scenario (which I did not need)